# How do I fire a Tag from within a Container on link click?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have the following Code Structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <a href="example.com">Link</a>
</div>
```

I have managed to create Tags that fire when Links are clicked that have an ID. But it seems to be a big hazzle to add an ID to each link and create a tag for each link.

I would like to create one tag that fires whenever a link within the container of the given ID is clicked. How exactly do I do that with the given options from Tag Manager? I have already created a Variable with the container ID. However I am not sure how to set up the Trigger.

Comment: nvm, I found a way. I'm using: [Click Element] [matches css selector] [#container]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track clicks on all links inside `#container` then your CSS selector should be `#container a`.

In GTM your trigger should be like that:
[image]